# MFP 7.1 Drop Down Menu not function well in iOS 11

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ibm-mobilefirst, xcode9, mfp

I'm using MFP7.1 and xcode 9 to develop my application on ipad platform. I'm facing an error when clicks on drop down menu button. When I select a value, the drop down list will close and re-open. Then, when I tap on the second drop down menu button, the first drop down list will re-open but the selection on the first drop down list will missing. The second drop down list will not appear.
The drop down menu button is function normally when I develop using xcode 8. This issue only happen when the application is develop using xcode 9 and running in iOS 11.

Anyone have an idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known case and happens because of Apple's Webview rendering. This is not a MobileFirst or Cordova issue.

The Apple forum that discusses this issue: 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84585